# How to apply edgesIgnoringSafeAre just if a condition is satisfied?

Tags: swiftui

I have this:

```
extension UIDevice {
  
  static func hasNotch() -> Bool {
    let bottom = UIApplication.shared.windows.filter {$0.isKeyWindow}.first?.safeAreaInsets.bottom ?? 0
    return bottom > 0
  }
}
```

I want to apply a

```
.edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.top)
```

just if a device has notch.

I have created this view modifier, with all sort of errors.

```
struct IgnoreTopSafeArea: ViewModifier {
    
  func body(content: Content) -> some View {
    if UIDevice.hasNotch() {
      content
        .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.top)
    } else {
      content
    }   
  }
}

extension View {
  func ignoreTopSafeArea() -> some View {
    self.modifier(IgnoreTopSafeArea)
  }
}
```

> Function declares an opaque return type, but has no return statements in its body from which to infer an underlying type

> Result of call to 'edgesIgnoringSafeArea' is unused

> Expression of type 'IgnoreTopSafeArea.Content' (aka '_ViewModifier_Content') is unused

how do I do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You done it almost, need using **()** and you do not need that func for reading notch.

```
struct ContentView: View {
    
    var body: some View {
        
        Color.red
            .ignoreTopSafeArea()
  
    }
}
```

---

**Version 1:**

```
struct IgnoreTopSafeArea: ViewModifier {
    
    func body(content: Content) -> some View {
        
        return Group {
            
            if hasNotch() {
                content
                    .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.top)
            } else {
                content
            }
            
        }
        
    }
    

}

func hasNotch() -> Bool {
    let bottom = UIApplication.shared.windows.filter {$0.isKeyWindow}.first?.safeAreaInsets.bottom ?? 0
    return bottom > 0
}
```

---

**Version 2:**

```
struct IgnoreTopSafeArea: ViewModifier {
    
    func body(content: Content) -> some View {
        
        return GeometryReader { geometry in
            
            Group {
                
                if geometry.safeAreaInsets.bottom > 0 {
                    content
                        .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.top)
                }
                else {
                    content
                }
            }
            .position(x: geometry.size.width/2, y: geometry.size.height/2)
            
        }
        
    }
}
```

---

**Works for Both Version:**

```
extension View {
    func ignoreTopSafeArea() -> some View {
        self.modifier(IgnoreTopSafeArea())  // <<: here ()
    }
}
```